# What is going on with convolution at the output of a circuit?

Tags: noise, convolution

Signal analysis newbie here. I was doing a project which analyzed the noise quality of a signal (it was a white noise generating circuit), and I found that the noise was more random for lower sample rates. I had a ton of capacitors in my circuit so I attributed it to parasitic capacitance on the Zener diode, but my supervisor suggested that another reason could be the fact that with a really high sample rate, my data will look less random -- in that the voltage signal would have varied less due to the fact that the output is a convolution of ... past voltage outputs? So, with a sufficiently slow sample rate this apparently won't happen.

In my head, I'm imagining a nominal output voltage and a few "past" measured voltages being convolved, forming some kind of a band, and this band moves as the signal varies randomly. With a slow enough sample rate, this "band" will have moved sufficiently far away from the previous sample to vary satisfactorily far enough so the voltage input I'm measuring is unaffected by the convolution of a past measured voltage. I know my language here is terrible, but I'm confused.

Can anyone elaborate more about what my lecturer was saying?

Comment: yes it's a suitable reasoning... I only want you describe what is a *nominal output voltage* ?

Comment: @Fat32 The voltage the output would display.

Comment: I remember, you had started a discussion on a very similar topic in this question, but didn't come back with any follow ups, there are two answers here, including one from myself https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66626/contradictory-results-from-power-spectral-densities-and-autocorrelation-in-shot

Comment: Let me repeat: *today it's nominal temperature outside* Now, what did I say ? Low, High, Average (of what), Typical (of what) ? what does **nominal** signify ? What sort of an adjactive it is ?